# Run expo-cli commands locally (using the local expo-cli)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have `expo-cli` installed globally in node_modules. I created a React Native Project in which I also installed `expo-cli` locally (because its in the `package.json` dependencies of the project).

I noticed that whenever I run an `expo-cli` command in my project, the global `expo-cli` is the one always called. I know this because, I updated the local `expo-cli` to a newer version, and when I try to run a command that exists in the newer version and not the former, its says that the command is not recognized. Or when I run `expo-cli -V` it shows the version of the global `expo-cli`, not the newer version installed locally.

### My question

How to force `expo-cli` commands to run with the locally installed version?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an npm script in your project's package.json for the expo command

   - `"expo": "expo"`
   - and use `npm run expo ...` to run you expo commands
2. In you project you can run `npm bin` / `yarn bin` to find the location of the locally installed binary files and invoke that directly.

   - `./node_modules/.bin/expo ...`